# NHibernate having trouble matching a DateTime object

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime, nhibernate

I have this simple action in ASP.NET MVC

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<EventDTO> Get(int bed, DateTime date)
    {
        using (var session = DBSessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Event>()
                .Where(e =>
                    e.Bed.Id == bed
                    && e.Date == date)
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => Mapper.Map<EventDTO>(x))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Using NHibernate, it complains that:

> "Input string '10:00:00' was not in the correct format.

And

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'

The column in the MySQL DB is of type DATETIME. I was using EF6 before, and since converted to NH. This is the last hurdle to complete the transition. Any idea what is causing NH to trip up? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the call stack:

```
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Hql.QueryLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformList(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractQueryImpl2.List()
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at OEETracker.Controllers.Api.EventsController.Get(Int32 bed, DateTime date) in EventsController.cs:line 27
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

And the event class:

```
public class Event
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Planned { get; set; }
    public virtual string EngineSN { get; set; }
    public virtual string Details { get; set; }
    public virtual EventType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Classification Classification { get; set; }

    public virtual Bed Bed { get; set; }
    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where's this coming from ""Input string '10:00:00' was not in the correct format." ..... it looks to me that its not so much NH but the mapper

Comment: I think Keith might be right, in the meantime can you post your Fluent map/XML map for your "Event" class please ?

Comment: Adding the `Event` class definition may help too. And the exception call stack will help checking if Keith is right.

Comment: @sh1rts I added the Event class. Take a look.

Comment: @Frédéric I added the stack trace. Take a look

Comment: That's not the map, that's the class itself i.e. the one you're mapping to. But it looks like you've solved your problem, so that's good :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `DateTime/Time/DateTimeOffset/Date` data types, I always tell explicitly the expected type in the mappings, since there may be some ambiguity when inferring from the underlying property type (.Net lacking a `Date` type, ...).

Usually for a db `DateTime`, I specify the NHibernate type `timestamp` on the property mapping. See the list of types available [on NHibernate reference documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes). Depending on your use case, there is a bunch of possible types to choose from.
You may also specify some non NHibernate types, as explained [in NHibernate reference documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property).

Comment: It turned out that the column in the DB causing trouble wasn't DATETIME, but rather a TIME field. Using `.CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan");` fixed the problem. Thank you!